# Decimal in iPhone Developing

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, decimal, int

I was wondering if any of you know how to use decimals in iPhone apps
i have this as a code.

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
a=.32;
b=.18;
c=a/b;
NSString *cstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", c];
NSLog(@"%@",cstring);
```

The NSLog should give 1.77777777 repeating
but it only gives 1.
I heard something about a NSDecimal and tried looking it up in Apple's Reference thing and found [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Does anyone either know what I did wrong or know something else that would work?

Comment: `b` is an `int` and when you assign it `.18`. It will be cast to `0`. At `c=a/b;`, you are trying to divide the number by `0` and hence the error.

Comment: Well you learn something new everyday! Thanks

Comment: Note that he wasn't getting an error. Rather the result was '1'.

Comment: Ya, I had no error, I figured out it was rounding the numbers. Alexsander's float thing is what I needed! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `a`, `b`, and `c` are declared as `int`s. Integers by definition are whole numbers. Try this:

```
float a = 0.32, b = 0.18, c = a/b; NSLog(@"%f", c);
```

Floats are floating-point numbers like decimals.

Comment: But why use floats? Why not actual decimals (`NSDecimal` as noted by the OP)?

Comment: An `NSDecimal` is a struct and to manipulate them you have to use many, many C functions, whereas you can add, subtract, multiply, and divide a `float` normally because it is a basic data type. In my opinion, using `NSDecimal`s for something like this is just way overcomplicating it.